# How to bind selected value to dropdown in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on Angular 5 application with dropdown. I have data coming from database, followed by mapped to javaScript object. I am trying to configure 'Selected' value but unable to do so.

in following code, option: [] --> 'optionSelected' defined if is selected value by true or false, schema structure as;

[image]

### component

```
 else  if(questionElementType=="dropdown")
 {

   let _dropBox = new DropdownQuestion({
     consultationId: questionsList[key].consultationId,
     questionId: questionsList[key].questionId,
     questionElementType: questionsList[key].questionElementType[0].title,          
     questionType: questionsList[key].questionType,
     title:questionsList[key].title,
     displayId: questionsList[key].displayId,
     key: questionsList[key].questionId,    
     label: questionsList[key].title,
     options:  questionsList[key].answerOptions.map(function(item){
       return {"key": item.preDefineAnswerOptionId, "value": item.text, "optionSelected": item.preDefineAnswerOptionId==questionsList[key].answer[0].answerValue? "true": "false" }
    }),        
     order: 1
   });

   this.mappedQuestions.push(_dropBox);
 }
```

### template

```
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'"> <small>dropdown</small>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select [id]="question.key" [formControlName]="question.key">
                <option *ngFor="let opt of question.options" [value]="opt.key" [selected]="optionSelected">{{opt.value}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>            
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to go here.  Personally I like binding the form control value to the entire selected object.  To do that you can update your view template to this:

```
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'"> <small>dropdown</small>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select [id]="question.key" [formControlName]="question">
            <option *ngFor="let opt of question.options" [value]="opt" [selected]="opt.optionSelected">{{opt.value}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>            
</div>
```

then in your component the form control value will be the entire selected item's object.  In other words

```
myForm.controls.question.value
```

will hold your entire selected object.

Make sure you instaniate your formGroup in your component like so:

```
 this.myForm= new FormGroup({
  'question': new FormControl('', []),
   ... (other controls here)
```

And then bind the form in your viewtemplate like this:

```
 <form  [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate autocomplete="off">
...controls in here
</form>
```

Comment: throw error, Error: Cannot find control with name: '[object Object]', plus these form created dynamically at run time so not sure if this error because of that

Comment: sounds like your formGroup isn't setp right make sure you're instantiating it similar to how I show in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

found answer as;

### component

```
 else  if(questionElementType=="dropdown")
 {
   let _dropBox = new DropdownQuestion({
     consultationId: questionsList[key].consultationId,
     questionId: questionsList[key].questionId,
     questionElementType: questionsList[key].questionElementType[0].title,          
     questionType: questionsList[key].questionType,
     title:questionsList[key].title,
     displayId: questionsList[key].displayId,
     key: questionsList[key].questionId,    
     label: questionsList[key].title,
     value: questionsList[key].answer.length<=0? null : questionsList[key].answer[0].answerValue.toLowerCase(),
     options:  questionsList[key].answerOptions.map(function(item){
       return {"key": item.preDefineAnswerOptionId, "value": item.text }
    }),        
     order: 1
   });

   this.mappedQuestions.push(_dropBox);
 }
```

### template

```
 <div *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'"> <small>dropdown</small>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select [id]="question.key" [formControlName]="question.key" [(ngModel)]="question.value">
                <option *ngFor="let opt of question.options" [value]="opt.key" >{{opt.value}} {{opt.key}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>            
  </div>
```